# javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host in Android while sending a Java mail with attachement

Tags: android, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send the attachment over the mail using smtp server( personal mail, not gmail).
Now while sending it is not reaching to the destination and giving 
javax.mail.MessagingException

Here is the full error which i am getting:

```
    In exception while sending mail****************************** javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.theftsecurity.net, port: 25;
04-27 13:26:38.933: D/Testing(17074):   nested exception is:
04-27 13:26:38.933: D/Testing(17074):   java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to mail.theftsecurity.net/203.124.98.72 (port 25) after 90000ms
04-27 13:26:38.934: D/Testing(17074): From Async send mail:Exception Message:Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.theftsecurity.net, port: 25
04-27 13:26:38.934: D/Testing(17074): From Async send mail:Exception local Message:Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.theftsecurity.net, port: 25
04-27 13:26:38.935: D/Testing(17074): From Async send mail:Exception trace:[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@42592a50
04-27 13:26:38.935: D/Testing(17074): From Async send mail:Exception Cause:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to mail.theftsecurity.net/203.124.98.72 (port 25) after 90000ms
```

In my code i have used this parameters to send the mail and i think some of them is causing the issue, but exactly don't know what is that basically:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

    if (_debuggable) {
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    }

    if (_auth) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
     if(_host.contains("gmail")||_host.contains("yahoo")){
           props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465"); 
           props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
         }
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Now, what i observed is, when i am using gmail, it is working fine. And i have tested the smtp in the below website

http://smtper.nanogenesis.fr/

And it is sending the mail to my desired mail id.
So can any one please tell where is the issue exactly..

Thanks,
Arindam.

Comment: Your app is not able to connect to the host and port due to network issues (firewall etc.). Are you sure you can make a connection to the host you mention?

Comment: Yes. I have checked on that way which i mentioned in the question. But i did not try with the attachment as i am trying to add a attachment here.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with attachment here. Your log clearly shows that the application is unable to connect to the host and port. I would try debugging the network settings with commands like `telnet mail.theftsecurity.net 25`, which obviously either seems to be down or blocked for a range of IPs (one of them being mine).

Comment: See also the JavaMail FAQ for [connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).

Comment: same issue any solution ?